# cuda is not available on my pytorch, but I can't find anything wrong with the version

Tags: python, pytorch

for some reason I have to use cuda version10.0 instead of upgrading it
The version of DriverAPI is higher than RunTimeAPI but somebody told me thats OK
Others who asked the same question at last found their version was not match. emmmm not like me

details here

OS:Windows10
Python 3.7&3.8 both tried

result of 'nvcc -V':
nvcc: release 10.0, V10.0.130

nvidia-smi:
NVIDIA-SMI 451.67       Driver Version: 451.67       CUDA Version: 11.0

conda list: cudatoolkit  10.0.130  0

import torch
print(torch.version.cuda)-----None
torch.cuda.is_available()-----False

Answer (score 1):

How did you install it ? I assume with pip. For pytorch I would recommend manually downloading the wheel from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html and install it with:

```
    pip install torch-1.4.0+cu100-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Assuming python 3.8 and linux. If you use something different make sure to select the appropriate version for your OS, Cuda version and python interpreter.

Comment: I ran the command on pytorch.org to update to v11.0 and everything OK now.  I installed v10.0 the same way  just from cudatoolkit=10.0 to cudatoolkit=11.0

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your torch, cuda and os versions are compatible from this official Pytorch tool - https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

The tool will tell you exactly which pytorch to install along with the command to run